# Møller Opeartors and dressing relations: what picture?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, scattering, hamiltonian, s-matrix-theory

Møller operators can be defined as (Urban, 2013;pg70):
\[  \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left|#1\right>} \newcommand{\braket}[2]{\left<#1|#2\right>}
 \Omega_{\pm}=\underset{t\rightarrow \mp 0}{\operatorname{s-lim}}\; e^{iHt} e^{-iH_0 t}\tag{1}\]
with the action of dressing being given as (Scadron, 1979;pg134):
$$\ket{\psi^\pm}=\Omega_\pm \ket{\phi}\tag{2}$$
for any time-independent state $\ket{\phi}$ of any energy. I am really confused about what picture everything is in. Here are my queries:

1. What picture do $H$ and $H_0$ need to be in, in $(1)$.
2. In $(2)$ what picture is $\ket{\phi}$ in - given that it is a time-independent state often defined as  e.g. $\ket{\psi(-\infty)}_I$.
3. In $(2)$ what picture is $\ket{\psi^\pm}$ in - given that I have seen a definition of the S-matrix in the Heisenberg picture as $\braket{\psi_f^-}{\psi_i^+}$.
4. How do the above three points mean that $(2)$ is a valid expression?

Please can someone explain these points to me.